# Spotfire - How to categorize dates - please see sample data below

Tags: date, spotfire, calculation

I have start dates and end dates, so in case if any date falls between start and end date i want to categorize it.

Sample:

```
Start Date  End Date    Category
3/9/2016    3/25/2016   A
4/11/2016   5/1/2016    B
12/1/2016   12/11/2016  C

Dates       Category    
3/11/2016   A   
12/3/2016   C
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Insert...Columns to join your "Dates" table to your "Start and End Dates" table
2. create a calculated column with `[Start Date] < [Date] AND [Date] < [End Date]`

it's really that simple